# C bytes - can't output char (only 8 bits)

Tags: c, int, byte, bit

Please take a look at my function:

```
int getByte(int x, int n) {
   int oneOnes = 255 << ( n << 3);
   int compute = oneOnes & x;
   //FIND A WAY TO RETURN CHAR (NOT INT)
   char result = (compute >> (n << 3));
   return result;
}
```

Everthing works great until the comment.  That is, I start with an integer `x`, and I want to take only a certain subsection (specified by `n`).  So what I did was make everything except the 8 bits I want to keep into zeros.  So for example, if the input was:

```
 1001011 10011011 00101011 01001011
```

And I want to keep only the 3rd group of bits (counting from the right), then the result would be:

```
 00000000 10011011 00000000 00000000
```

So I've managed to do that correctly.  The issue is, I need to return *only* the bits that I want (with the zeros cropped, as a `char`).  Despite creating a `char result` and returning that, what's being returned is still the 32 bit value.

Any help? Thanks!

To be clear: For `00000000 10011011 00000000 00000000`, I want *only* `10011011` to be returned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you're trying to use signed integers to do this, but shifts of signed integers are not well defined -- whenever the bit pattern happens to be a negative value, bad things happen.

Instead, as is usually the case when doing bit manipulations, you want to use unsigned integers:

```
unsigned int getByte(unsigned int x, unsigned int n) {
  unsigned int oneOnes = 255U << ( n << 3);
  unsigned int compute = oneOnes & x;
  return (compute >> (n << 3));
}
```

Its even easier if you do the masking AFTER the shifting, as then you don't need to shift the mask:

```
unsigned int getByte(unsigned int x, unsigned int n) {
  return (x >> (n << 3)) & 255U;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is not a 8-bit value as your function is declared to return the `int`, not a `char` and you are returning not the result but compute. Also, if you would like it not to be sign-propagated somewhere use unsigned char as a result type:

```
unsigned char getByte(int x, int n) {
  int oneOnes = 255 << ( n << 3);
  int compute = oneOnes & x;
  //FIND A WAY TO RETURN CHAR (NOT INT)
  unsigned char result = (compute >> (n << 3));
  return result;
}
```

But the more efficient implementation is this one:

```
unsigned getByte(int x, int n) {
   return (x >> (n << 3)) & 0xFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a careless typo, but in the actual program I had it return the result as your edit....still not the char I'm looking for.  But it looks like it returns negative numbers...

Comment: yes, as if the most significant bit of `char` is one then the result is negative number. then change the return type and/or result type to `usigned char`

Comment: *"it looks like it returns negative numbers"* - then cast the function as "unsigned char". BTW the function should perform a range check on the value of parameter *n*.  And since a full byte is returned, the bit masking is superfluous, i.e. `result = x >> (n << 3)`.